# Correct tense usage

Tags: grammar, tense

It was an interesting panel of people, each of whom have been in the language pedagogy business for many years

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem not of tense, but of subject-verb agreement in number (singular or plural). 'Each' is **always** singular, so the singular verb form 'has' is the correct choice.

> Each is often followed by a prepositional phrase ending in a plural
>   word (Each of the cars), thus confusing the verb choice. Each [...] is
>   always singular and requires a singular verb.

[Subject verb agreement](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sv_agr.htm)